# should your models be aware of your API version?

Tags: api, rest, sinatra, versioning, software-design

We are going to implement a versioning system to our API code, the system is built on sinatra and there will be a default API version and clients will be able to choose a specific version adding the HTTP Accept Header.

Now I'd like to understand if you'd strictly keep the API version information inside the controller or you allow the api version to be passed inside your models in some way. If you keep it in the controller, what are the cons of propagating the API version in the models?

Comment: What are the benefits? I don't see how this would help you - if you're running integration tests against the API (no mocking of the models!) and they pass then what's the need? Either the models support the API or they don't. Unless I've misunderstood, in which case @Nicholas' answer is good.

Answer (score 0):

In a RESTful API design, versioning is done through choice of media type, which I believe is what you are trying to do. If I understood the second paragraph correctly, you are asking if the version information should be inside the delivered response too (i.e. part of the document model)?

Such a decision is arbitrary, but many formats carry version information inside themselves in case they pass through a lossy system where metadata (such as version information) might be lost. I would recommend putting it in your model for this reason.

Comment: I think you're right in what you've advised about keeping the version in the response, but I think they were referring to model as in data model from the MVC pattern. Probably :)

Comment: that's what gets written to disk/socket, so it's the same thing, isn't it?

Comment: I would say that the HTTP response and the model (in an MVC) are not the same, even though the response will contain a representation of the model to some degree, but I think (for me) the OP needs to clarify what they're talking about.

Comment: I think your argument for putting the version in the body - that a lossy system might remove the metadata (response headers) - is flawed. You could say the same thing about the other metadata (`Date`, `Content-Length`, etc.). Go ahead and include them in the body, too. Now you've gone and built a whole layer on top of HTTP. Something REST tries to avoid.  Also, What if a new version of your API causes a change in how the version itself is represented? That doesn't happen with the `Content-Type` header (unless HTTP itself changes - gulp), where API version info should be stored.

Comment: yes, but metadata such as date & content length are saved in the file system, version information is not. So while I agree that this could be the first step on a slippery slope for someone who is not thinking, including only information that is lost when a HTTP response is saved to disk is sensible.

Answer (score 0):

Versioning your API doesn't mean your controller handles versioning internally and then communicates with the model which also handles versioning internally. Instead, it means you should have different versions of your controller and model that you swap in and out at runtime based on the version of the API in the request.

Now, I presume from the mention of Sinatra that you're using Ruby. I know little about Sinatra or Ruby, but [I answered a similar question for ASP.NET MVC 4](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15094532/326110) and discussed a versioning framework written by Sebastiaan Dammann.

Maybe see if a similar framework already exists for Ruby.