# Web.Api routing additional parameters to route

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing

How can I add additional parameters to web api route? I want to add one parameter to default route and support versioning my api, sth like this: `api/{version}/{controller}/{action}/{id}`

I know that {controller} is mapped **automatically** with controller name and `{action}` metho name, but what or how could to `{version}` mapped?

p.s. yeah, sound very weird question, but...

Comment: You would need to implement a new controller selector.  There are open source implementations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your WebApiConfig.cs , you need to have -

```
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{version}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { version = 1, id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

And when you execute the values controler getjson action -

```
    public string GetJson(string id)
    {
        return "me";
    }
```

You get following output -

[image]

If you want to version your WebAPI endpoints, then use this [namespaces approach](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/03/08/using-namespaces-to-version-web-apis.aspx). Alternatively, you can also use [Http header approach](http://barelyenough.org/blog/2008/05/versioning-rest-web-services/). Or else simply [route approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13982896/versioning-web-api-actions-in-asp-net-mvc-4).